# Joomla menu disappeared

Tags: menu, joomla-3.5

Recently because of some errors in my joomla site, I re-install `joomla 3.5.1` Persian. Now I have a problem on `creating menu`. some fields in creating new menu is disappeared. I clear my browser and I also clear host `tmp` folder but no thing changed.

This my Joomla administator -> menu -> new:

[image]

and this what should be (this is picture of created menu):

[image]

As you see, there is a lot of differences. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It seems that there is a mix-up over `Menu` and `Menu Item`. Visit "[Adding A New Menu Item](https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_a_new_menu_item)" Documentation.

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between adding a Menu and editing a Menu Item.